# Using deployment tool from command window

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Currently I am developing a solution that requires interaction with external software. As a result I can only properly test it after I build the solution as a dll file.

Currently I take these steps

1. type 'deploytool' (to open the deployment tool)
2. click the button 'open project'
3. Find and select the project that I want to open (always in the same location with the same name but apparently matlab does not remember this)
4. Click the build button

Currently I do this several times per day and it is really simple, but simply annoying. 
Therefore I hope that someone can give me a way to automate step 2-4, perhaps using a script?

If this is not possible I would also appreciate a way to change the default opening folder for the deployment tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help deploytool` says you can specify the projectname and build option as a second argument:

```
deploytool -build projectname
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I only checked the doc.
I can use deploytool(projectname) but deploytool -build projectname does not work

Comment: It sound like you have trouble getting the arguments in the function. What about `deploytool('-build','this_is_my_project')`, that's the same as `deploytool '-build' 'this_is_my_project'`.

Comment: Just for future reference: The solution will work on recent versions of Matlab. (I believe they added this functionality somewhere between 2007 and 2010)